# wave vectors and finite size (standing wave)

Tags: crystals

If a take a chain of spring and masses and I put hard boundaries conditions. I know I get standing waves that are combinaison of k and -k where k is the wave-vectors.

Now, I can do the same with a 2D lattice, if the boundaries are a square along the direction of the lattice, I should get standing wave of $\pm k_x$ and $\pm k_y$

My question is now if i take another shape, like a triangle for my lattice. What will happen? I should get a standing wave with mixture of $k_x$ and $k_y$, but i cannot see how to determine the allowed point $(k_x, k_y)$ in the reciprocal states for a given geometry that is not along the axis of the lattice

Comment: I think there's a problem here--in that a displacement of a mass in $y$ also loads the $x$ spring--so there's going to be some sort of coupling. Of course in the small displacement limit, I suspect the problem is separable.

Comment: I actually don't want to go to the small displacement limit, I kind of suspect that there will be standing wave with term like $\cos(k_x x/2 +k_y y/2)$ for the triangle case